# momentjs - Date (Year, month, day) to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, milliseconds

I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) in my app. But I don't understand it very well.

I need to get a date in **milliseconds**, but I need only day, month and year. Others should be set to `0` (Hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds)

I'm trying with some like this:

```
var a = moment();
a = moment(a, "YYYY MM DD").valueOf();
```

But it returns milliseconds with extra info I don't want.

How can I get only milliseconds from days, months, and years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the milliseconds from midnight of a given date, you don't need moment.
Just use the `setHours` method:

```
let date = new Date();
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(+date);
```

With moment, you can use `startOf`:

```
let date = moment()
date.startOf('day');
console.log(+date);
```